# I/O error in channel Chunked connection error while trying to pull jobs from jenkins

Tags: jenkins

After my research i found that we need to update the value Dhudson.diyChunking to true. But i have below queries:
Why do we need to change this value? 
What is the impact on changing the value?

Comment: Where is the query?

Comment: these are my questions:
1)Why do we need to change this value? 
2)What is the impact on changing the value?